# How to use R's testthat to unit test individual files?

Tags: r, testthat

I'm just now getting into unit testing with R and finding it tough sledding so far.  What I'd like to do is go into the R console, type `test()` and have testthat run tests for all the files in my R package.

Here's my environment:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.4 (El Capitan)
```

And directory structure:

```
math
-- R
------ math.R
------ add.R 
------ subtract.R
-- tests
------ testthat.R 
------ testthat
---------- test_add.R
---------- test_subtract.R
---------- test_math.R
```

With the following samples of relevant files:

math.R

```
source('add.R')
source('subtract.R')

doubleAdd <- function(x){
    return(add(x,x) + add(x,x))
}
```

add.R

```
add <- function(a,b){
    return(a + b)
}
```

testthat.R

```
library(testthat)
library(math)

test_check("math")
```

test_add.R

```
context('add tests')

test_that('1 + 1 = 2', {
    expect_equal(2, add(1,1))
})
```

The Error:

In the R console, I get the following result:

```
library(devtools)
test()
<b>Loading math
Loading required package: testthat
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) (from math.R#1) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'add.R': No such file or directory
</b>
```

However, if I switch the working directory by `setwd('R')` and run math.R, `doubleAdd` functions just fine.  Also, if I delete math.R or move math.R out of the 'R' directory, `test()` works just fine.

How am I supposed to setup these files to have `test()` run tests for all my R files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are building a package you shouldn't be using `source`.  You simply export your functions in the `NAMESPACE` file or use [roxygen](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/index.html) to do it for you.  You are likely getting the error because it is looking for `add.R` in whatever your working directory is.

Here is a run through starting from scratch for me with basic package setup.

add.R - in R/ directory

```
#' @export
add <- function(a,b){
  return(a + b)
}
```

test_add.R - in tests/testthat/ directory

```
context('add tests')

test_that('1 + 1 = 2', {
  expect_equal(2, add(1,1))
})
```

Run in console

```
library(devtools)
# setup testing framework
use_testthat()

# update NAMESPACE and other docs
document()

# run tests
test()

Loading math
Loading required package: testthat
Testing math
add tests : .

DONE
```

**Note** - you actually don't even need to export `add`.  If it is an internal function you are testing it will still work.  Just stop using `source` in your package.